# make a link holding a model

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a string Data in my model that can be pretty long. I'm trying to take the first 150 chars and then make it clickable, and when the link is clicked a new div should appear with the whole message. Below am I using  tag, but I dont know how to give it a unique ID and make it store my item.Data.

Can someone help me with some ideas?

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Level)
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Source)
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <a ID="?">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data).ToString().Substring(0, 150) ...</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Count)
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
```

Comment: Do you want an id attribute on `DisplayFor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you'll just need something like this:

```
<a class="show-data" href="#AllData">
    @item.Data.Substring(0, 150)
</a>
<div id="#AllData" style="display:none">
    @item.Data
</div>
```

Then, a bit of JS:

```
$('.show-data').on('click', function () {
    $($(this).attr('href')).toggle();
});
```

Take note, though, for simplicity of the example, I just assigned the div an id of `AllData`. Since this is inside a foreach loop, you'll need to use something to make each id unique. This could be the id of the item or you could use a `for` loop instead of `foreach`, and then use the index. Just be sure to make the `href` of the link and the `id` of the div match and be unique for the page.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="@Url.Action("YourControllerActionResultName", new { id=item.Data})">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data).ToString().Substring(0, 150) </a>
```